# ExecuteScalar: Object reference not set etc

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

Guys I need a little help. This is my first time developing an app that has DB in it, considering this, please forgive my blunders.

I am trying to obtain a boolean value from database and applying if, else loop on it...but it keeps throwing "Object reference not set" error on ExecuteScalar function.

Here is the code :-

```
        string sql = " // here is my sql query ";
        string connectionstring = " // Here is my connection string.... ";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql,connection); 
        command.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        bool ev = (bool)command.ExecuteScalar();
        if (ev == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("some error");
        }
        else
        {
            // Some Code
         }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Help will be really appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Have you checked the return values? It could be that it didn't connect or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the query returns null. Try this:

```
bool? ev = (bool?)command.ExecuteScalar();

if(ev.GetValueOrDefault(false))
{
   MessageBox.Show(...);
}
```

The `?` means nullable, so it this way the value returned from the query is allowed to be `null`.

Comment: Thank you, your answer seems logical but I cant seem to be able to apply your method.
If value returned in ev is null, I want to perform some task. How do I go about doing that? and if the value is returned is 1, I want to show messagebox with text "Already added".

Comment: Remove the `GetValueOrDefault` part. Check for `HasValue`. You can check `ev == null` then.

Comment: Displays the following error on "  (ev.HasValue == null)"
the result of the expression is always "false" since a value of type 'bool' is never equal to 'null' of type 'bool'?

Comment: Sorry, my comment was unclear. Check for `HasValue` or `ev == null`.

Answer (score 0):

do some validation for the `ExecuteScalar` return value as below

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql,connection)) 
{
    connection.Open();
    object ev = command.ExecuteScalar();
    bool flag; 
    if(ev!=null)
    {
       // return as null value, do Task 1 
    }else if(Boolean.TryParse(ev.ToString(), out flag) && flag)
    {
       // return as true value, do Task 2   
    }
    }else
    {
       // return as false value, do Task 3   
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup "ev" is returning null as there is nothing present in that particular column that I am retrieving.
How do I applying some code if ev is null? like I want to show a messagebox saying EV is null.

Answer (score 0):

Patrick's comment was spot on. Here is a complete example...

```
string sql = " // here is my sql query ";
string connectionstring = " // Here is my connection string.... ";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql,connection)) 
{
    connection.Open();
    bool? ev = (bool?)command.ExecuteScalar();

    if (ev.HasValue == true && ev.Value == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("some error");
    }
}
```